# Wait and do something on few websites in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want full load 3 websites with one browser (not in same time) and do some tasks.

My code;

```
     string[] websites = 
     {
        "www.facebook.com", "www.bug.hr", "www.htmlgoodies.com"
     };

     string[] inputs = 
     {
        "first", "second", "third"
     };

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     {
        Browser1.Navigate(websites[0]);
     }
     private void Browser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     if (Browser1.Url.ToString().Contains(websites[0])) 
     {
        while (Browser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        Browser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", inputs[0]);
        Browser1.Navigate(websites[1]);
     }


     if (Browser1.Url.ToString().Contains(websites[1])) 
     {
        while (Browser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        Browser1.Document.GetElementById("mainsearchtext").SetAttribute("value", inputs[1]);
        Browser1.Navigate(websites[2]);
     }

     if (Browser1.Url.ToString().Contains(websites[2])) 
     {
         Browser1.Document.GetElementById("search-input").SetAttribute("value", inputs[2]);
     }
```

SCOND WAY;

```
int n;

private void Browser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)

    {
           n++;
         if (n == 1) 
         {


            Browser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", inputs[0]);
            Browser1.Navigate(websites[1]);
         }


         if (n == 2) 
         {


            Browser1.Document.GetElementById("mainsearchtext").SetAttribute("value", inputs[1]);
            Browser1.Navigate(websites[2]);
         }

         if (n == 3) 
         {
             Browser1.Document.GetElementById("search-input").SetAttribute("value", inputs[2]);
         }
```

In second way problem is that n sometimes can be differently than expected.

I have problem with load second and third website. I also try on some another ways but don't work. So my goal is to open the pages one after the other and do some tasks on every page. If you have some another way, I would be grateful.

Comment: "I also try on some another ways but don't work" - Show us what you tried & tell us what exactly didn't work.

Comment: Please never ever ever use `Application.DoEvents()`. It is only there for backward compatibility for Visual Basic 6 applications. It will cause you far more grief than it helps.

Comment: Browser every time stop load second page. What I will use to reply Application.DoEvents()? I'm try on many ways do that, but every time don't work.

Comment: I'm update my second way in post. Please help me, any advice?

Comment: @Enigmativity

i'm curious what you use instead of `Application.DoEvents()`?  i don't really do winforms development in c# mostly console/web  but when i did a c# course at uni last year (free 7 to drag up my GPA) that's exactly what they were teaching to use to maintain GUI Usability/updates during a process where you might need to animate something or change a progress bar status on the form.

Comment: @Nikerym - What they taught you was wrong. `.DoEvents()` can cause all sorts of re-entrancy issues and make debugging very hard. They should have taught you how to use the background worker to multi-thread your application. I use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this kind of thing. But you could more simply use timers to check if your pages have loaded. It's more complex than `.DoEvents()`, but it would be so much more robust.

Comment: I don't use it day to day,  with most of my dev being websites/web services i have no need for an interface (i use HTML5/CSS/JS for web interfaces client side obviously)

But very interesting to hear,  thanks for the response.

Comment: @Enigmativity I also try with timers but didn't work, can you give me some example with timers to find out where I'm wrong?

Comment: @marklinkl - I've posted an answer, but I can't test it so you might need to do some debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm tested it, now works perfectly. Thanks again, this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
int current = 0;
string[] websites = { "www.facebook.com", "www.bug.hr", "www.htmlgoodies.com" };
string[] elements = { "email", "mainsearchtext", "search-input" };
string[] inputs = { "first", "second", "third" };

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(websites[current]);
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 250;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(elements[current]).SetAttribute("value", inputs[current]);
        if (++current < websites.Length)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(websites[current]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @marklinkl - You know what? If this works as-is then that tells me that the `.DoEvents()` was causing you problems.